# Can you have different transition times on the same transition property?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a settings button (img with an icon as the src) that I want to spin when the cursor is hovering, and then scale down and back to normal when the user presses on it.

```
#settings-button:hover {
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

#settings-button:active {
    transition: transform 50ms ease-out;
    transform: scale(0.90);
}
```

With the current code, it scales down at the correct speed, but it takes 1s to get back to the normal size. If I change the duration in :hover it works fine, but then it spins so fast you can't see it.

Is there anyway to have different durations for the same transition property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [CSS Houdini](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Houdini).

But it's possible to achieve what you're looking for, by simply having 2 CSS animations and toggling between them with JavaScript. One will simply be faster or slower than the other.

Comment: Appreciate it! That did it.

Comment: No worries man :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the issue I was having.

```
#settings-button:hover {
    animation: rotate 1s ease-in-out;
}

#settings-button:active {
    transition: transform 50ms ease-out;
    transform: scale(0.90);
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {transform: rotate(-360deg)};
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).